SQL add rows with new dates and retain the cumulative sum
I am using Snowflake.
I have the following table:



ID
Date
CumSum




100
2024-07-31
5 000


100
2024-08-31
6 000


100
2024-09-30
7 000


200
2024-07-31
5 000


200
2024-08-31
6 000



I want the following (if there is no new amount during the month, currently the table does not contain any new numbers):



ID
Date
CumSum




100
2024-07-31
5 000


100
2024-08-31
6 000


100
2024-09-30
7 000


200
2024-07-31
5 000


200
2024-08-31
6 000


200
2024-09-30
6 000



I expect to retain the cumulative sum and if in the future new amount will be in the future periods, it should be added to the cumulative sum

Would there only ever be forward dates missing data?  What version of SQL are you using?

Have you considered to create a view instead?

I don't understand. Please add more context.

How do you define future periods? Up to current month?  Last existing month in your table?

This works but has the downside of requiring you to hard code the dates in the unpivot clause. You may need to use dynamic SQL to get around that with a large number of dates.
with t0 as (
   select *
   from sums
   pivot (max(cumsum) for adate in (any order by adate))
   order by id),
t1 as (
   select *
   from t0
   unpivot include nulls (cumsum for adate in ("'2024-07-31'","'2024-08-31'","'2024-09-30'"))
   order by id)
select
   id,
   adate,
   coalesce(cumsum, lag(cumsum) over(partition by id order by adate)) cumsum
from t1
order by id, adate;




ID
ADATE
CUMSUM




100
'2024-07-31'
5000


100
'2024-08-31'
6000


100
'2024-09-30'
7000


200
'2024-07-31'
5000


200
'2024-08-31'
6000


200
'2024-09-30'
6000



